# Unable to access Vue3 methods when using `<script setup lang="ts">`

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need to use Vue in a non-Vue Class and I'm using the Composition API. (It's a Chrome Extension and it doesn't in this case make sense to have the whole thing as a Vue App).

I'm instantiating the Vue Instance in the normal way, and injecting it into the Class.

```
// typescript
// content.ts
const vueFooInstance = app.mount(vueRoot) as unknown as FooMethodsInterface;
new BarClass(vueFooInstance);

// BarClass.ts
Class BarClass
{
 constructor(vueFooInstance){
  this.vueFooInstance = vueFooInstance
  this.vueFooInstance.someMethodOnFoo();   // error appears here if using <script setup> : 
   // this.vueFooInstance.someMethodOnFoo() is not a function
 }
}
```

So the issue is that it seems that a Vue returns a Proxy Object while the method should be available it is not *if I use the  approach.

However, if I use the 'traditional' approach the problem is resolved:

```
export default defineComponent({
 setup(){
   someMethodOnFoo(){
   }
  }
  return {
    someMethodOnFoo,
  }
}
```

So the question is:

How do I make the issue go away if I use the `<script setup>` approach or is it not possible? (Also, it would be nice to know why the issue occurs with `<script setup lang="ts">`

(I believe it's a typescript issue with `defineExpose` but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you faced this issue is that when using `<script setup>`, the code is transformed in a way that hides component internals by default, and you need to use `defineExpose` to make specific methods or properties accessible externally.
In Vue 3 Composition API with `<script setup>`, you should use [defineExpose](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) to explicitly expose methods or properties that you want to access from outside the component. This is different from the options API, where you would simply return an object with the methods you want to expose.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineExpose } from 'vue';

const someMethodOnFoo = () => {
  // Implementation of someMethodOnFoo
};

defineExpose({ someMethodOnFoo });
</script>
```

Comment: Strangely, I thought I'd tried that but it does the trick. I think you don't need the import { defineExpose } from 'vue'; as I think it's export default